# Highlight selected menu item not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get [this snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/9eABK/108/) from JSFiddle working on my site. I copied the HTML directly, used the CSS inline and put the Javascript in an external file. Sadly, the functionality isn't working. You can view what I've done on [my test page](http://www.kiaabdullah.com/test/). I'm not experienced so any advice as to what I'm doing wrong would be very helpful.

**Code from my test page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Javascript test</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

<style>
body {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

/* jQuery UI theme settings */
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    margin: 1px 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
    margin: 1px 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;

}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-highlight { 
    font-weight: normal; 
    margin: -1px; 
    color:red;
}

/* Demo settings */
#menu {
    width: 30%;
}
</style>



</head>

<body>
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Aberdeen</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Ada</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Adamsville</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Addyston</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Delphi</a>

        <ul>
            <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Ada</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Saarland</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Saarland</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Salzburg</a>

        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#">Delphi</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Ada</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Saarland</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Delphi</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Ada</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Saarland</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Perch</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Amesville</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the dev console? Are you loading `jquery.ui`lib?

Comment: The original JFiddle is using JQuery2.0.2, while you seem to be using JQuery1.6.1.

Comment: You have forgot to include Jquery UI. Download it from here https://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to include all exnternal JS libraries from JS fiddle, you can find list as shown below.

For the specific case you can include it like this:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-lnH4vnCtlKU2LmD0ZW1dU7ohTTKrcKP50WA9fa350cE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-TZWGoHXwgqBP1AF4SZxHIBKzUdtMGk0hCQegiR99itk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[image]

UPD:
Move your `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>` to the end, just before `</body>`. Your code should be executed after loading of the page. So it's even better to put in to corresponsing event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).menu({

        select: function( e, ui ) {

            // Remove the highlight class from any existing items.
            $( this ).find( "a.ui-state-highlight" )
                     .removeClass( "ui-state-highlight" );

            // Adds the "ui-state-highlight" class to the selected item.
            ui.item.find( "> a" )
                   .addClass( "ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all" );     

        }

    });

});
```

UPD2:
And finally, include JQueryUI CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

I recommend you to read some Getting Started tutorial for JQueryUI to sort out such issues: https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/

Comment: Thank you for this. The header now includes the following but it still doesn't work. Any ideas? I tried your exact code snippet as well to no avail.


`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You included jQuery, but you also need to include jQuery UI. Since you're using the google CDN for jQuery, you can use that same CDN for jQuery UI. Add this after your jQuery script tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

You can also use the CDN on jquery.com here https://code.jquery.com/ui/

Comment: Thank you for this. The header now includes the following but it still doesn't work. I used the ui version used in the JSFiddle and also tried the one you used. Sadly, neither worked.


`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>`